# Theoretical aspect - sorting a specific array in worst case O(n)

Tags: arrays, sorting, theory

Say there is a way to sort an array with n elements in worst case runtime O(n). Also we know / assume that it takes constant time to compare each element of the array (this assumption is a must, we cannot ignore it).

Will it be possible to sort an array like that in worst case O(n) if: Every elements with an even index are sorted, from smallest to biggest.
And every elements with an uneven index are sorted from biggest to smallest.

```
Example: 
We have array A = 1, 10, 3, 8, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 2, 11
Even index: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 (Index 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10) --> Sorted smallest to biggest
Uneven index: 10, 8, 6, 4, 2 (Index 1, 3, 5, 7, 9) --> Sorted biggest to smallest
Aim result sorted: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 (works in O(n)?)
```

Possible to sort it completely in worst case O(n)?
Just a theoretical question, no need code. I would say the even indexes are fine, they are sorted smallest to biggest and our result also needs to look like that, smallest to biggest. However their position are a big problem, what if the elements in uneven index are smaller? We would have to change positions then, but the assumption says it can compare in constant time, so in O(n). But in general, the sort for arrays is done in O(nlogn), isn't it?
So that would mean it wouldn't work in O(n) worst case runtime?

Comment: Is this from a class homework assignment/question?  What is the practical relevance?  Adapting a merge-sort is the obvious answer.

Comment: @Hugues - for O(n), the solution is an adapted merge, not a merge sort.

Comment: @rcgldr What you mean by adapted merge? Does that mean we use specific things of merge sort and combine it with something else?

Comment: @frytkii - The solution is to merge the evens going forwards with the odds going backwards. It's a single merge operation of two sorted runs (the second run accessed from right to left). If this has to be done in place, it gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you very much so far! Also thanks to Hugues. One last question, could this really be done in O(n) using your adapted merge? I heard merge is done in O(n) at least, if I remember that correctly. So it should really be possible?